# How to mock EF 6 Async methods using JustMock?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, moq

I am trying to Mock Entity Framework 6.0.2 Async methods using JustMock. I am following [testing with async queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async) but it is write using Moq I am trying to convert this into JustMock with help of [Mock Multiple Interfaces](http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/scenarios-mock-multiple-interfaces.html) but getting an exception :

> The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement
>   IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement
>   IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous
>   operations. For more details see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

Here is my code :

```
var dummyData = GetEmployeeSkills();
var mockSet = Mock.Create<DbSet<EmployeeSkill>>();
(mockSet as IDbAsyncEnumerable<EmployeeSkill>).Arrange(x => x.GetAsyncEnumerator())
         .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<EmployeeSkill>(dummyData.GetEnumerator()));

(mockSet as IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>).Arrange(x => x.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<EmployeeSkill>(dummyData.Provider));

(mockSet as IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>).Arrange(x => x.Expression).Returns(dummyData.Expression);
(mockSet as IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>).Arrange(x => x.ElementType).Returns(dummyData.ElementType);
(mockSet as IQueryable<EmployeeSkill>).Arrange(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(dummyData.GetEnumerator());

var mockContext = Mock.Create<TimeSketchContext>();
mockContext.Arrange(x => x.Set<EmployeeSkill>()).Returns(mockSet);

baseRepository = new BaseRepository<EmployeeSkill>(mockContext);

private EmployeeSkill GetEmployeeSkill()
    {
        return new EmployeeSkill
        {
            SkillDescription = "SkillDescription",
            SkillName = "SkillName",
            Id = 1
        };
    }

    private IQueryable<EmployeeSkill> GetEmployeeSkills()
    {
        return new List<EmployeeSkill>
        {
            GetEmployeeSkill(),
            GetEmployeeSkill(),
            GetEmployeeSkill(),
        }.AsQueryable();
    }
```

Test :

```
[Fact]
public async Task DbTest()
{
   var data = await baseRepository.FindAsync(1);
   Assert.NotEqual(null, data);
}
```

Repository :

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
{
    protected readonly DbContext InnerDbContext;
    protected DbSet<T> InnerDbSet;

    public BaseRepository(IDbContext innerDbContext)
    {
        InnerDbContext = innerDbContext as DbContext;
        InnerDbSet = innerDbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual Task<T> FindAsync(long id)
    {
        return InnerDbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id == id);
    }
 }
```

Interface :

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    DbSet<T> Set<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Context :

```
public class TimeSketchContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkill { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample code. I got my test working now.. tq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JustMock can mock non virtual methods when you are writing

```
var mockContext = Mock.Create<TimeSketchContext>();
mockContext.Arrange(x => x.Set<EmployeeSkill>()).Returns(mockSet);
```

it will mock the `DbContext.Set<>` and not your `IDbContext.Set<>` so you get the exception.

There are at least 2 solution to this:

- Mock your `IDbContext` interface

  ```
  var mockContext = Mock.Create<IDbContext>();
  ```
- Or change back your `BaseRepository` to use a `DbContext` instead of your interface:

  ```
  public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IEntity, new()
  {
      protected readonly DbContext InnerDbContext;
      protected DbSet<T> InnerDbSet;

      public BaseRepository(DbContext innerDbContext)
      {
          InnerDbContext = innerDbContext;
          InnerDbSet = InnerDbContext.Set<T>();
      }

      public virtual Task<T> FindAsync(long id)
      {
          return InnerDbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
      }
  }
  ```